# Simple jquery validation - custom position error message placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I am using **jquery validate plugin to validate number in a form** , how can i place the returned error message under the input button , i am unable to achieve,

Here is my image with the issue and what i need,pls check - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsRko.png

**Please suggest me how to put the error message in a custom Div under the button instead of default underneath.**

Here is my code:

```
<section id="contact" class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Contact Form Demo</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span12 contact-form">

                        <form action="mail.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal contact-form" id="contact-form">
                          <!--<?php $formKey->outputKey(); ?> -->
                          <fieldset>  

                              <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputPhone">Phone</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <input class="input-80" name="phone" type="text" id="inputPhone" placeholder="inc. country &amp; area code">
                                </div>
                              </div>


                              <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <button type="submit" value="Send" class="btn" id="btn-place">Send!</button>
                                </div>
                                <div >place here</div>
                              </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- javascript -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>



        <script>

            // contact form validation
            $(document).ready(function(){

             $('#contact-form').validate(
                 {
                  rules: {
                    name: {
                      minlength: 3,
                      required: true
                    },
                    email: {
                      required: true,
                      email: true
                    },
                    phone: {
                      minlength: 11,
                      required: false,
                      number: true
                    },
                    subject: {
                      minlength: 3,
                      required: true
                    },
                    message: {
                      minlength: 20,
                      required: true
                    }
                  },
                            highlight: function(label) {
                    $(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
                  },
                  success: function(label) {
                    label
                      .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                      .closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
                  }
                 });

                // contact form submission, clear fields, return message,script no shown here

        </script>
```

Comment: Try to limit your code to the relevant bits (in this case you probably only need to show us the rules for `phone`)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All you need to do is specify the [errorLabelContainer](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorlabelcontainer) in your options and specify the div you want the errors to go into:

```
$('#contact-form').validate({
     //all your other options here
        errorLabelContainer: '#errors'
});
```

Then just make sure you specify that your `place here` div has the id `errors` like this:

```
<div id="errors"></div>
```

See a working example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/aaEFQ/  (note that I also specified the `wrapper` option, which you'll probably want if there are multiple errors).

Comment: I Tackled the issue in a Different manner using: errorPlacement

Comment: Can you suggest me how to ajax POST LATER only after VALIDATION ?

Comment: use the `submitHandler` option of Validate - it is only triggered when the form is valid.

Answer (score -1):

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  if((element.attr('name') === 'color[]')){
    error.appendTo("div#errors");  
  }
  else if(element.attr('name') === 'font[]' ){
    error.appendTo("#font-error");  
  }
  else{
    element.before(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: color[]' or font[]  is the name of checkboxes

div#errors or  #font-error is div where u want to show your custom error message

Comment: You should [edit] that information into the post, not leave it as a comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.